# How could I effectively read complex numbers when they are written as (a+bi) form?

Tags: c, structure, complex-numbers

I want to make a program that adds and multiplies complex numbers using structures. Up to here it seems very straight-forward to me, as I know how to create structures and make functions that compute this.

But I have a problem with reading the input values, as I want them to be written according to these rules:

1. Real numbers(imaginary part==0) are written as numbers themselves.
   ex) Input: 90
2. Imaginary numbers(imaginary part!=0) are written with brackets.
   ex) Input: (3 + 6i)

So for example, I want to achieve the below:

Input: 80 + 100

180

Input: (3-2i) * 2

(6 - 4i)

Input: (3 + 4i)*(2 + 2i)

(-2 + 14i)

I know that if I read the operation first and then read each number separately this problem would be solved. But if I wanted to read complex numbers as a whole distinguished by parentheses, I do not know how it could be done.

The difficulty that I had was not in the computing algorithm, but in reading the input values with scanf(). When reading with scanf() I do not know when there would be parentheses, so I feel it difficult to read two complex numbers and save them into my complex structure.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct dc
{
    int real;
    int imag;
};
typedef struct dc dc;

dc dc_add(dc a, dc b)
{
    dc t;
    t.real=(a.real+b.real);
    t.imag=(a.imag+b.imag);
    return t;
}
dc dc_multi(dc a, dc b)
{
    dc t;
    t.real=(a.real*b.real-a.imag*b.imag);
    t.imag=(a.real*b.imag+a.imag*b.real);
    return t;
}

int main()
{   
    dc result;
    dc a;
    dc b;

    printf("Input: ");
    /*Couldn't figure this part out*/
    printf("(%d %d)\n",result.real,result.imag);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI the current C language has native complex types.

Comment: You'll need a small parser for arithmetic formulas (+,-,/,*) with (nested?) parentheses, The single addition to get from real to complex arithmetic is "numbers followed by the letter `i` are imaginary numbers". Although sounding very complicated it is simpler than the fight with `scanf`.

Comment: @R.. — but it doesn't have native I/O for the complex types; you have to print the real and imaginary components separately, formatting them manually.  There's no `printf()` or `scanf()` conversion specifier for 'complex'.

Comment: Could you ever have `(80 + 100) * (90 - 15)` (a real number computation) or will you only have complex numbers in parentheses?  This affects the complexity of the parsing you have to do. You can only tell whether you've got a real expression or a complex number when you get `i` or `)`.  However, using `scanf()` or `fscanf()` is a bad idea.  Reading the line with `fgets()` or something similar and then using `sscanf()` is a possibility; writing a custom parser is another.  Will you ever have floating point complex values (`(1.234 - 9.876i)`)?  Will you allow spaces before the `i`: `(2 - 3 i)`?

Comment: How will you format a complex value where the imaginary part is 0?  Where the real part it 0?  Does that mean you need to allow `14i` without parentheses?  Within parentheses?  Could you have to deal with `((3 + 4) * (4 - 2i))` — only one complex number there?  Or `((3 + 4i) * (2 - 6i) / ((3 - 4) * (12 + 2i))` — 3 complex numbers in 4 expressions.

Comment: A complex number is expressed after calculation as `a + bi` ; `a` and/or `b`  could be zero. Don't worry about the `()`'s, it's just a notation indicating you cannot "mix" the real and the imaginary parts.  You could ask the user to input separately real and img parts, with 0 meaning one of the parts being null. Since you'll have to do the math anyway, you could input a whole line (see `fgets`), e.g. `36+3i*(4i-7-2*(2i+4i))`, then do a recursive function to evaluate that, always keeping temp. results in a `struct dc`. Converting the expression to RPN (search) first makes it easier to handle.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler I don't mean to be too rigorous about this program, I will always add or multiply two complex numbers(whether their real or imaginary part is 0), and that result would not be around parentheses. And no, something that could be simplified such as (80+100) or (90-15) is not allowed. And I suppose there would not be any spaces between the number and i. Also I would only deal with integer values.

Comment: That's probably feasible as a first step. It was inevitable that you'd do most if not all computation using complex arithmetic, but it was important to establish the I/O rules. Summarizing: parentheses will only be used around complex numbers. Hypothesizing: with complex numbers, both the real and imaginary parts will always be present, and the real and imaginary components will always be integers. Construction: You'll need to read a line of input, split it into numbers, complex numbers, and operators, guided in part by the presence or absence of parentheses, probably not using `sscanf()`.

Comment: I'm tempted to say `lex` and `yacc` but that's only if you like to experiment and learn with some heavy tooling rather than getting the input job done :)